# what is the replacement for 'overflowchanged' event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The `overflow` property for a div tag in my cshtml page is set to `auto`. I'm trying to run a javascript function when the page overflow changes. For example when the page is short there is no scrollbars and when it gets long a vertical scrollbar appears in the right side of the div.
when the page gets shorter again, the scrollbar disappears.
I found this [link](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbnnejo.php) here introducing the overflowchanged event but it won't work. After a bit of search I found out that it's deprecated and is no longer available. Now my question is what is the replacement for it and if there is none, what are your suggestions for solving my problem?

Answer (score 1):

For **Firefox** we have the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/overflow) and [`underflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/underflow) events. If you are only interested in the *change* of overflow, you can have them both call the same function.

In the example below I've added some extra lines to let you force an overflow event by toggling the contents of the `<div>`. You can also fire the events manually by opening the example in full page view and resize your browser window.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div'),
    text = el.innerHTML

el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML == text ? "Click this to toggle length of the content. This is a long line of text forcing the contents of the element to overflow its dimensions. Eventually this will have scrollbars appear and fire the overflow event." : text
})

function overflowChanged() {
    console.log("Overflow changed")
}

el.addEventListener('overflow', overflowChanged)
el.addEventListener('underflow', overflowChanged)

// Or with jQuery you could go with a one-liner:
// $(el).on('overflow underflow', overflowChanged)
```

```css
div {
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
   Click this to toggle length of the content. Will fire an event when the overflow changes.
</div>
```